# Nodejs Localhost issue on Chrome

Tags: node.js, google-chrome, localhost

I am just learning node and I am having some issue running locally on chrome. When I try hitting localhost:3000. When I start the project in my terminal i get my first log that it is listening on 3000, but then when I hit the page it just tells me that the webpage is unavailable and i don't see any more logs. But it does work in Safari and Firefox.

Also if I switch it over to port 80 and run it on my actual server it works fine in chrome. Ive tried clearing all my cache, running in incognito and restarting my comp. Nothing seems to work.

Chrome suggests that it might be a proxy issue, but I'm not why or how something like that would have changed, as this problem only started in the last couple of days and I haven't changed anything.

Comment: Can you please show us some code, especially how you start the Node.js server?

Comment: I am using express. So it is fairly standard  `var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

app.listen(port, function() {
  console.log("Listening on " + port);
});`

Comment: Strange, looks perfect and should work out of the box using `http://localhost:3000` ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of localhost:3000, try **127.0.0.1:root folder**

Comment: Interesting, I wasn't exactly sure what "root folder" would be within the scope of my project,so on a whim i tried 127.0.0.1:3000 and that worked.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is caused by a bug in Chrome's Asynchronous DNS feature. If you turn that feature off by going to:

chrome://flags

and then disabling the "Built-in Asynchronous DNS" feature, Chrome will recognize localhost again.

Comment: I'll look into that when I have some time this weekend.

Comment: I filed a bug report here:

https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=396309

and found that the problem only shows up on a Mac when there are commas in the hosts file.